# Hibernate Select SubQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss, hql

I have the following hql query:

```
JgrelhasListBack = session.createQuery("from Jgrelhas where jtabuleiros.id=? and id<? order by id desc").setParameter(0, tabuleiroId).setParameter(1, grelhaId).setMaxResults(limitenovo).list();
```

I need to get the last 5 Results so what i did was order it desc and get max results 5. But i need it ordered by Asc...

I found a solution that was to make the query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I tried to replicate it in hql but didn't get it to work:

```
JgrelhasListBack = session.createQuery("select (select Jgrelhas from Jgrelhas where jtabuleiros.id=? and id<? order by id desc ) from Jgrelhas order by id asc").setParameter(0, tabuleiroId).setParameter(1, grelhaId).setMaxResults(limitenovo).list();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to reverse desc ordered list:

```
List jgrelhasListBack = session.createQuery("from Jgrelhas where jtabuleiros.id=? and id<? order by id desc")
    .setParameter(0, tabuleiroId)
    .setParameter(1, grelhaId)
    .setMaxResults(limitenovo)
    .list();
return java.util.Collections.reverse(jgrelhasListBack);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know i could reverse an entire collection like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do sub-queries with from clause in HQL. It's only supported in select/where clause.

Either try by native SQL query

(OR) Convert to where clause as below.

```
select Jgrelhas from Jgrelhas
where id IN   
(select id from Jgrelhas
where jtabuleiros.id=? and id<? order by id desc )
order by id asc
```